# Is Inspector Spacetime a reference to a series that really exists?

Tags: reference, community

In the series *Community* the characters Abed and Troy love to watch the series *Inspector Spacetime*.

It feels like it is a reference to a series that really exists.

So does it? And if so, what is its name? So is it kind of a parody? Or does it really exist under another name?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Inspector Spacetime* is a direct parody of the series [*Doctor Who*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who).

Some clear parallels:

- Inspector Spacetime travels in a time traveling phone box:

  [image]

  The Doctor travels in a time traveling police box:

  [image]
- The enemies of the Inspector are know as the Blorgons:

  [image]

  Which are a parody of the Daleks from *Doctor Who*:

  [image]

Answer (score 14):

In addition to [onewho's excellent answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36380/18124), I'd like to point out how Inspector Spacetime was initially introduced into the show.

In *3x01 Biology 101*, Britta gets Abed interested in a British TV show called [Cougarton Abbey](http://community-sitcom.wikia.com/wiki/Cougarton_Abbey) (because *of course* Britta only watches European TV), which is an obvious parody of the [British series Downton Abbey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downton_Abbey) (and a wink to the US series [Cougar Town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cougar_Town), which, if nothing else, you should remember from the [*My Diner With Abed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_Film_Studies) episode).

The one thing that is important to know about real-world UK series is that they are usually quite short by American standards. The original *The Office*, for instance, had just 2 seasons of 6 episodes each. So Abed is devastated when he finds out that *Cougarton Abbey* ends after only 6 episodes, with all the main characters dying.

To cheer him up, Britta tells him of a popular British sci-fi series that has been running for decades, *Inspector Spacetime* ([Doctor Who holds the Guinness world record for longest running sci-fi show](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/entertainment/5390372.stm)).

This keeps Abed happy in several ways as it appeals to his new-found interest in British TV, as well as his existing passion for sci-fi, without the risk of running out of episodes to watch anytime soon.

Comment: You are my hero. Can't say why but that side note answered all I never dared to ask about the that season ^^

Answer (score 5):

*Inspector Spacetime* is a direct parody of *Doctor Who*.

> Inspector Spacetime is a direct homage to the long-running BBC science fiction TV show Doctor Who.
>   The show within the Community universe follows closely the story of Doctor Who with the Inspector and his partner traveling in a red telephone box known as the X7 Dimensionizer time booth, the counterpart to the T.A.R.D.I.S. - and using his Quantum Spanner to fight alien creatures such as the Blorgons.

Source: [Community Wikia](http://community-sitcom.wikia.com/wiki/Inspector_Spacetime_%28television_show%29)